# How to write data to csv which doesn't has fix count of rows in multiple lists with help of pandas library in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

While writing data to csv with help of pandas, The output I got doesn't have all values. Because of unequal values present in list.

The code finds the lowest value present in the 3 list and then writes the data with exact number of rows found in the lowest list.

Here's the code:-

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


a1 = []
b1 = []
c1 = []


for a in range(1,6):
    a1.append(a)

for b in range(1,7):
    b1.append(b)

for c in range(1,9):
    c1.append(c)

a1.append('None')
b1.append('None')
c1.append('None')


df = pd.DataFrame(zip(a1, b1, c1),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
path = 'D:\\bhavyanew\\python_projects'
filename = dt.datetime.now().strftime("ABC_%d_%b_%y_%I_%M_%p.csv")
p1 = os.path.join(path, filename)
df.to_csv(p1, index = False)
```

Output I got in csv:-

```
a       b       c
1       1       1
2       2       2
3       3       3
4       4       4
5       5       5
```

None       6       6

Output I want in csv:-

```
a       b       c
1       1       1
2       2       2
3       3       3
4       4       4
5       5       5
None    6       6
        None    7
        None    8
```

Things I tried with other libraries(csv-writer) and it worked:-

```
pathout = 'E:\\Bhavya Lodaya\\
filename = dt.datetime.now().strftime("ABC_%d_%b_%y_%I_%M_%p.csv")
p1 = os.path.join(pathout, filename)
with open(p1, 'w') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(["a", "b", "c"])
    for row in zip_longest(laptop, desktop, server):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This code worked but it adds a blank line after every append in csv.

I want my expected output with help of pandas.

Comment: How? Can you guide me or show me a way to do that?

Comment: Can you tell me how should I do that?

Comment: @9769953, I got your point, But I'm asking where should I include this code? Because I tried a1.append(None) below a1.append(a) but it didn't worked.

Comment: @9769953, I've updated the code in question as per your requirement, But still it doesn't work. Would you post the answer rather than commenting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess around with trying to figure out how many Nones to append to each list. Let pandas do work of aligning on an index by converting each list to a series first:

```py
import pandas

a1 = []
b1 = []
c1 = []

for a in range(1,6):
    a1.append(a)

for b in range(1,7):
    b1.append(b)

for c in range(1,9):
    c1.append(c)
    
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'a': pandas.Series(a1),
    'b': pandas.Series(b1),
    'c': pandas.Series(c1),
})
```

And I get:

```
     a    b  c
0  1.0  1.0  1
1  2.0  2.0  2
2  3.0  3.0  3
3  4.0  4.0  4
4  5.0  5.0  5
5  NaN  6.0  6
6  NaN  NaN  7
7  NaN  NaN  8
```

Or more consisely:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    col: pandas.Series(numpy.arange(N))
    for col, N in [("a", 6), ("b", 7), ("c", 9)]
})
```